# How to trace origin of a javascript behavior, specifically - adding hash to my urls

Tags: javascript, debugging, hash

Someone wrote some bad code that causes a hash to be added to the end of some urls on our website. This also results in an extra history item, without the hash, so that the user has to hit "back" twice when they should only have to hit back once.

In Chrome's developer console, I've tried searching Elements and all Sources (ctrl-shift-f) for "history" (only used once, not apparently related), as well as "#", "hash", and other things and I have not found what is adding the hash symbol to the url and changing the history.

Is there any way to trace this?

EDIT:

I tried setting a breakpoint in Chrome in the Sources tab, checking the box under Event Listener Breakpoints/Load/hashchange. But chrome does not stop. I don't know why.

But the following did work to stop script execution at the `hashchange`.

I set a breakpoint in Chrome before the hash is added, then added the following in the console:

```
jQuery(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
        debugger;
});
```

Then I continued the script, and it paused again, presumably just after the hash was added (it's there now).

Now how do I view the current execution state? Who triggered the hashchange?

Comment: Could it be a link with `href="#"`? That would explain why there is no trace of it in the JS files.

Comment: @11684 There are links like that but then something must be triggering a click on them. Is there any way to trace the source of the `on('hashchange'` ?

Comment: Not that I know of; by the time that event handler is called, the offending code is no longer the current execution state, the event handler is. This is because JavaScript is single-threaded, so to execute the event handler, the JavaScript interpreter has to finish other code (in this case code adding a hash) first, before executing your event handler.

Comment: @11684 so how do you track down a problem like this? There must be some way other than searching through the code for hours or executing it line by line, right?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of JS somewhere where it will always execute.:

```
jQuery('a').on('click',function( e ) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or trace the specific a element with:

```
jQuery('a').on('click',function( e ) { 
    console.log(this);
});
```

But even if you trace it you won't be able to do anything because if you remove href="#" click on 'a' will refresh the page, so you need to prevent 'a' tag default behaviour anyway

Comment: The hash in the href attribute could also be replaced `onclick="return false"`, doing exactly the same as e.preventDefault() in an event handler.

Comment: That will require going and manually adding on-click to every a though

Comment: @Gurami I am not worried about the manual clicks. It's that something is automatically either clicking on "#" or else changing the current url to add "#". There is only 1 page load happening, but two items in history added.

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze the logging attached to click did not work. It may not be a click that is the cuplrit. But doing this gave me the entire window object: `jQuery(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
        console.log(this);
});` But I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Now on the right I see `paused on "hashchange" event listener", and under it I see an a with properties `newURL` and `oldURL`. I am trying to see if I can find out more by examining this object.

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze Very good point. I thought inline was cleaner, but that was of course mistaken, I see now.

Comment: @Buttle Butkus hashchange logging won't give any useful info, log the click on 'a' tag like `consle.log( this, this.href );` this way you will get A element and it's HREF attribute

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze The problem is that "click" is not firing. The hash is definitely being changed, but the exact method that is affecting the change is still a mystery.

Comment: @Buttle Butkus try `jQuery(window).on('hashchange',function( e ) { console.log( e ); });` if you haven't already

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze I try that and it gives me the Window object, i.e. *everything*. When I look under the Window's even property, I see it has a HashChangeEvent and I can see the newURL and oldURL. But I still don't know where the code is being executed.